# Kohler bathtub faucet dripps

Tags: bathtub

We recently moved in to a house. The bathtub faucet keeps dripping after it it has been turned off. I have replaced the cartridge, gaskets, and cleaned a bunch of the buildup off inside. Some of these attempts have helped the problem some but it still dripps just not as much. Sometimes we can stop it if the dial is in just the right position when off. Other times it may stop, suddenly dropped a bunch for a few seconds, stop for a little while then start up again.

Comment: Do not know exactly how they work or the parts, but it almost sounds like a valve seat(sealing surface) needs refacing/resurfacing(deep cleaning/grinding, smoothing).

Comment: Kohler is notorious for what I'd call having a, for lack of better words, double cartridge. You remove the normal one but in the back of the valve base is another nylon base that has "o" rigs that need to be replaced. That piece is damn near impossible to get out.

Comment: Sounds like an answer, @JACK.